# Connect server to local network

Tags: networking, connection, windows-server-2012

Yesterday I have installed Windows Server 2016 on Virtual Box. I have added the users and everything, now I need to connect it to local network. But I can't find the way. Can anyone give me any advice how to do it?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your needs.
You might want to set up bridged network or NAT. See the [manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) for details.
The easiest approach is to set up bridged network.
Open the Settings dialog of a virtual machine, go to the "Network" page and select "Bridged network" and device in the drop down list.
If you have DHCP on your network, VM will get IP assigned automatically, no need to do anything else.